# Change button width

Tags: html, css

I'm kinda begginer in html.
I have this code in html

```css
.header{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/30/3/T07WKU.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 
}

    .header h1{
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 75px;
        font-family: 'Akaya Telivigala', cursive;
        color: #FFF
    }
    .header h1:hover{
        color:lime;
    }
    
    .sth{
        height: 400px;
        background-image: url(https://mcdn.wallpapersafari.com/medium/43/0/KIieEY.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    #space{
        height: 20px;
        background-color: #FDF0D5
    }
    
    .sth h2{
        margin: 0;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 100px;
        font-family: 'Akaya Telivigala', cursive;
        font-size: 35px;
        color: pink;
    
    }
    
    #aa{
            padding: 30;

    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Akaya+Telivigala&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<h1> Vous êtes les bienvenues dans notre site web </h1>
</div>
<div id="space"> </div>

<div class="sth">
<h2> Vous pouvez vous enregistrer pour de benificiez de nos services </h2>
<h2 id="aa"> <button><p> Sign up </p></button> </h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

when i try to change button width with the id  aa, it dont stay in the center like the other h2 and go the left, what to do to prevent it from changing position and giving it bigger width
thanks

or even if there is another way to put it in the center please help me

Comment: You can change the width of the button by referring to css as `h2#aa button { width: 200px; }`.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header{
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/30/3/T07WKU.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 
}

    .header h1{
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 75px;
        font-family: 'Akaya Telivigala', cursive;
        color: #FFF
    }
    .header h1:hover{
        color:lime;
    }
    
    .sth{
        height: 400px;
        background-image: url(https://mcdn.wallpapersafari.com/medium/43/0/KIieEY.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    
    #space{
        height: 20px;
        background-color: #FDF0D5
    }
    
    .sth h2{
        margin: 0;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 100px;
        font-family: 'Akaya Telivigala', cursive;
        font-size: 35px;
        color: pink;
    
    }
    
    #aa{
            padding: 30;

    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Akaya+Telivigala&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<h1> Vous êtes les bienvenues dans notre site web </h1>
</div>
<div id="space"> </div>

<div class="sth">
<h2> Vous pouvez vous enregistrer pour de benificiez de nos services </h2>
<h2 id="aa"> <button style="height:200px;width:200px"><p> Sign up </p></button> </h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

There's two things in `css` `height` and `width`. I just changed height and width of `button`. You can try also. `style="height:200px;width:200px"`